# Doctrine Inheritance mapping, selecting by type and subtype parameter

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a superclass `LibraryCommon` and 4 subtypes: `Library`, `PurchasedLibrary`, `PurchasableLibrary` and `PersonalLibrary`.

`Library` is a simple extension of `LibraryCommon` with no additional fields, `PurchasedLibrary` has a user entity. In one instance, I want all `Libraries` and all `PurchasedLibraries` that belong to a certain user.

So I created a method in the `LibraryCommonRepository`:

```
public function findLibraries($user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->where('l INSTANCE OF Library')
        ->orWhere('l INSTANCE OF PurchasedLibrary AND l.user = :user')
        ->setParameter(':user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

However, this errors out as `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 182 near 'user = :user': Error: Class LibraryCommon has no field or association named user`.

**Am I missing something, or do I really need to join two seperate queries to get the result I want?**

---

Additionally, if I do not provide the user and do like this:

```
public function findLibraries()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->where('l INSTANCE OF Library OR l INSTANCE OF PurchasedLibrary')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

The generated query looks this:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM 
  library l0_ 
WHERE 
  (
    l0_.type IN ('library') 
    OR l0_.type IN ('purchased')
  ) 
  AND l0_.type IN (
    'library', 'personal', 'purchased', 
    'purchasable'
  )
```

Is there any way to make the query just do `WHERE l0_.type IN ('library', 'purchased')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add the User mapping to your LibraryCommon, just the private attribute, default to null, and keep getter and setter in your PurchasedLibrary.